# Ionic serve loading wrong app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created my first Ionic app using CLI, so I did:

```
ionic start my-project --v2 blank
```

I run `ionic serve` command inside the project's folder, and I can see the brand new project in the browser. I did some changes in the project and run `ionic serve` again, perfectly fine.

I created another project with CLI:

```
ionic start second-project --v2 blank
```

Then, I run `ionic serve` from inside the second project's folder and the first one is actually loaded, not the second one.

What did I miss?

Comment: Clear history in your browser and try again ...

Comment: @VickySmart thanks, you actually directed me to find the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't try to clear the browser history but I remembered that I did play around with Service Workers in my first app, it was a PWA.

So I ran `ionic serve` then opened ***Chrome's Developer Tools*** and found out that it was still there, so I *Unregistered* the service worker and deleted it under the *Cache Storage* section.

Stopped and ran `ionic serve` again and it loads the right app now.

Comment: I had the same problem. I thought I was going crazy. I started to go crazy, You are my savior!

Comment: That fixed it :) ty

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved this issue.

Chrome was still using the cache from that previous app. I ran ionic serve it loaded my wrong app, then I opened the Developer Tools, and under Applications tab, Service Workers option, it was there.

I clicked the 'Unregister' option, then under 'Cache Storage' section I deleted the registered previous application's cache with the right click option. This solved my problem.